# How to only read digital variable in data by numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a file like that:

```
NAME : SciFest2013 Hard
COMMENT : O-Mopsi
TYPE : TSP
DIMENSION : 19
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : HVS
NODE_COORD_SECTION
1 29.7442602 62.60293178
2 29.744674041895 62.598619926779
3 29.741911701886 62.598623656726
4 29.742301019133 62.598961607715
5 29.745234623579 62.602818631625
6 29.741105111344 62.599147986679
7 29.744691895349 62.60205558507
...
19 29.739264424401 62.597253963228
EOF
```

I only want to read the digitial part, for example, in this file, from 1 to 19, I use:

```
rawdata = np.loadtxt("SciFest2013.txt", skiprows=6, max_rows=19)
```

However, in others file, it is uncertain that the row of number data, someone is from 1 to 6, someone is from 1 to 12...so how to only read the middle part(number part)?
(it always have 6 rows need to skip in the front of data, so skiprows=6 is good enough)

Comment: not sure, I understand. Why don't u read all the lines? Is the EOF last line is what bothers you?

Comment: @LiorCohen Thanks for your reply again because I only want to read the digital part, to skip string part.

Comment: but if the first lines are skipped, what prevents you from reading until the end of the file? is it the EOF line?

Comment: @LiorCohen Hi, Lior, for example, if I use rawdata = np.loadtxt("SciFest2013.txt", skiprows=6), so the last row include EOF right? I was wondering if there is some function like:: loadtxt('test.txt', [7:-2, :])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I understand that you want to read from line 7 until the end of the file and the `EOF` is what produce an error.

The simplest solution is just to ignore it by the `comments` optional parameter.

for example:

```
np.loadtxt("SciFest2013.txt", skiprows=6, comments='EOF')
```

if you have other comments youe can use a list of comments: `comments = ['EOF', 'other comment']`